# Spring Boot extending CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Hibernate in a Spring Boot app. I'm making a new CrudRepository for all my Model objects, to do basic CRUD tasks. They look like this:

```
@Repository
public interface FoobarCrudRepo extends CrudRepository<Foobar, Long> {
}
```

But then I always need to do some additional things, like custom search queries with inequalities and such. I follow a pattern like this:

```
@Repository
public class FoobarDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Foobar> findFoobarsByDate(Date date) {
        String sql = "select fb from Foobar fb where createdDate > :date";
        ...
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

My question is, can I combine these two concepts into a single class? I tried making it an abstract class, like so:

```
@Repository
public abstract class FoobarCrudRepo extends CrudRepository<Foobar, Long> {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Foobar> findFoobarsByDate(Date date) {
        String sql = "select fb from Foobar fb where createdDate > :date";
        ...
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

But then Spring didn't create a bean for it.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using spring-boot then you definitely should be using spring-boot jpa. I think it is the best option. You will even do not need to write a DAO class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could probably accomplish this. If you really need absolute control try this

```
interface FoobarRepositoryCustom{
    List<Foobar> findFoobarsByDate(Date date);
}

interface FoobarRepository extends CrudRepository<Foobar, Long>, FoobarRepositoryCustom

public class FoobarRespoitoryImpl implements FoobarRepositoryCustom{
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;


    public List<Foobar> findFoobarsByDate(Date date) {
    String sql = "select fb from Foobar fb where createdDate > :date";
    ...
    return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

There is also the possibility to go a simpler route and the query can be auto generated for you based on the method name. In your example you could just add this to your FoobarCrudRepo and Spring should do the rest assuming Foobar has a property named CreatedDate

```
List<Foobar> findByCreatedDateGreaterThan(Date date);
```

For reference on how Spring can generate queries based on the method name see this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Your link led me to http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query which, in my opinion, is a better approach for being easier to read and more explicit. Great answer!

Comment: I tried the absolute control approach to overwrite the repositorys deleteById method. This forces me to explicitly cast my repo like `((FoobarRespoitoryImpl ) repo).findFoobarsByDate(date);`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You can create your custom base repository by extending CrudRepository. You will need to annotate it with `@NoRepositoryBean` so it doesn't get picked up as a repository.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `abstract` keyword.

```
@Repository
public abstract class FoobarCrudRepo extends CrudRepository<Foobar, Long>
```

Spring will not create a bean for a class unless it is a concrete class.
That's why you are getting a bean for it.

Comment: Having @Repository on an interface works. So the fact that it's not a concrete class has nothing to do with it. The fact that it's "not an interface" obviously plays a role here, but why?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.myproject" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.myproject.sprinbootapp.repository")
    @EntityScan("com.myproject.sprinbootapp.model")
    public class SpringbootAppWithDatabaseApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringbootAppWithDatabaseApplication.class, args);
        }
    }

@Service
public class TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    private List<Topics> topics = new ArrayList<Topics>();

    public List<Topics> getAllTopics(){
        List<Topics> listOfTopics = new ArrayList<Topics>();
        topicRepository.findAll().forEach(listOfTopics::add);;
        return listOfTopics;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Topics {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Topics(){

    }
 getters and setters...
}

public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topics, String> {

}
```

Comment: Why would you iterate over the List, when findAll gives you a List already?

Answer (score 0):

we can use the JPA `EntityManager` for direct sql actions:

```
public interface VerificationsRepository extends
    CrudRepository<Verification, Integer>,
    DAOAccess
{ }

interface DAOAccess {
   List findByEmail(String email);

}

class DAOAccessImpl implements DAOAccess {
   @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

    public List findByEmail(String email) {
        String sql =
            "select * from verifications where email = ?";
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Verification.class)
            .setParameter(1, email);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```